# How do we know where to truncate when doing Mie calculations?

Tags: scattering, error-analysis

Solutions of Mie-Scattering theory are infinite series solutions. In practical calculations, they are truncated at 1, 2 (Rayleigh limit) or 50 or 100 terms (computation calculations). But how do we know where to truncate, without computing the terms first and checking where error minimizes?

Comment: Can one do a series expansion in terms of some small parameter perhaps?